# This Question about how do i learn from basic As3 to advanced as3

Tags: actionscript-3

This Question about how do i learn from basic As3 to advanced as3 , as i want to become professional in as3.And work as freelancer.

can anybody guide me how to reach to the peak of Action-Script-3.

This question seems to be really funny to many but this is the most basic question in my mind
1) which way to go.
2) what steps i should follow.
3) how should i do my first project professionally.
4) how do i become excellent in as3

Comment: You may need to give a little more description of your background (whether you started with Java, C etc, what is your current state, do you want to master animations or RIAs)

Answer (score 2):

- understand OOP classes and packages.
- Inheritance and polymorphism
- keep all content in external xml files
- dont ever put any code in your fla
- start building a library of reusable classes for common tasks ( a util library )

start working with the [Essential Actionscript 3.0](http://books.google.com/books?id=gUHX2fcLKxYC&dq=colin+moock+actionscript+3&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=en&ei=ntoTTJilBIT58AaNq5G2Cg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CC0Q6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=colin%20moock%20actionscript%203&f=false) and you are on your way...
read and understand this entire book and you will be rolling

Answer (score 2):

I believe actionscript 3.0 and Flash in general allows you work on a wide variety of projects:
from interactive *rich media web interfaces*, to *interactive video*, *animation*, *games*, *desktop applications*, *rich internet applications*, *physical installations*, *creative and abstract pieces*, etc.

It's up to you what you want to do, but I'm guessing if you **start with something that motivates you**, something that you enjoy working on and learning, it's a sure way forward
and it will make the boring bits more fun, and that's what it should be about: **FUN**!

It doesn't matter if it's actionscript or something else you want to learn, enjoy learning/challenging yourself and you'll get there faster than you think.

**Answer 1.):**

With regards to actionscript, based on what you want to do with it, there are a couple of good starts. Let's say you're interested in just the code, not planning to use the Flash IDE much or at all, and your aim to develop great applications. as @David Morrow said, Colin Moock's  [Essential Actionscript 3.0](http://www.moock.org/eas3/) is great. Also his guide [From the Ground Up](http://www.moock.org/lectures/groundUpAS3/) is a compressed version of the book.

An easier lecture, but packed with hands-on tips to getting things done in actionscript 3.0 is [Rich Shupe's Learning Actionscript 3.0](http://www.learningactionscript3.com/), also from O'Reilly. This might help you get up to speed with project you might have in mind.

**Answer 2.) and 3.):**

In short you have at least two routes:

- easy/practical start where you learn
  by doing small mini projects, but
  keep in mind there are gaps to fill
  in order to move on to complex
  projects
- a 'harder'/more theory based start,
  that will cover advanced topics, so
  you will ready to take most projects
  out there, simple or complex.

**Answer 4.):**

It also important to keep in mind that **there is no substitute for experience**! Learn how ever it feels comfortable, but plan time for practicing/writing a lot of code/failing/fixing/repeating. Don't worry about getting things wrong! I don't know any programmer that can write a complex project perfectly from start to finish. Basically all projects out there are the result of this loops of failing/fixing/learning/ if you want to put it this way.

**Never be afraid of getting things wrong** ! You learn more this way, than getting things right, but not fully understanding why, also, you can discover something new. You can't run
into happy accidents if you don't have accidents at all.

As you progress you will like some things more than others. It is important to try everything when you learn. **Knowing what you don't like is just as important as knowing what you like**. Don't take everything for granted and form your opinions while learning.

You mentioned peaks. It's great to aim high. As I mentioned earlier, actionscript can be used for so many things, that it's hard to be the best in all areas. [Andre Michelle](http://www.andre-michelle.com/) and [Joa Ebert](http://blog.joa-ebert.com/) for example are very talented developers and have a lot of experience with sound. [Chris Georgenes](http://mudbubble.com/) on the other hand is a very talented animator. I wouldn't expect roles to swap anytime soon. If it helps, choose people that are actionscript virtuosos, **get inspired** by their works, there are plenty of them out there.

HTH,
George

Answer (score 1):

The simplest, yet probably most important answer is: Use it.

The only way you'll become advanced in AS3 (or any language) is to just start using it.  Do some experiments, maybe create some small tools for yourself, or find an open source app and start contributing to it.

Books will help, but they're no substitute for actual experience using the language.

Comment: I follow this. You cannot say that reading 99 books and knowing them from start to end will make you an advanced programmer. Just try and pick something you want to do, some application or something for fun, and start building it. No matter how advanced you are you will always face problems and solving them means experience, this is what is made of an advanced programmer: experience! :)

Answer (score 1):

As they say, you need to learn to crawl before you can walk.

You need a **solid** understanding of programming. See David Morrow's answer for things you should know. Also add to the list a knowledge of datastructures.

Start programming. As George Profenza said, start with a simple project first and something that you will enjoy doing. If you undertake something too big you may end up disillusioned. The best thing about working on little things often is that you will encounter certain problems, and you will learn through experience on how to tackle them.

Once you have the basic hang of things start looking at other people's source code. Visit blogs of various well known flash developers and go through their code. Learn from the best. My blogrole is a list of such people.

After a while, maybe a year or so you will be a decent AS3 programmer. Remember AS3 is just a tool. What seperates the men from the boys is being able to solve problems. Start tackling more complex problems, for example, develop a voxel engine or something along those lines. The best programmers tend to experiment with problems in the field of computer science. In doing so, they become knowledgable on various things like 3D rendering, Audio etc and develop unique skills placing them on the cutting edge.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm a visual programmer, i only learn as a means to an end - I want to make things.
If you are as i am - then here's what I recommend to go from basic AS3 to advanced AS3.

Make a game. OR, and this might be an even better route.
Clone a game that you like - e.g. tetris, bomberman, pacman
I know it a single statement answer.... not fancy, but - you will HAVE to learn so much in the process of creating it.